# What is "empty" expression in django rest_framework.serializers.BaseSerializer

Tags: python, django

Here is the `__init__` method in django's `rest_framework.serializers.BaseSerializer` class.

```
def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
    self.instance = instance
    if data is not empty:
        self.initial_data = data
    self.partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    self._context = kwargs.pop('context', {})
    kwargs.pop('many', None)
    super(BaseSerializer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

By default `data=empty`. `empty` is not imported or defined anywhere in `serializers.py`. And I never saw this before in python (Im still beginner tho).

How does `empty` work here? From the first look to me it seems that `empty` is an undefined variable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empty` is defined in `rest_framework.fields`: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L39.

It can be used in the place that you mention because it's being imported at line 46: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L46.

Comment: Nice one @SimeonVisser. Using sublime and cant see where objects are coming from. :(

Comment: @Raituha Do yourself a favour and get an IDE like PyCharm.

Comment: @idjaw used to have PyCharm with licence on my work computer. But now I'm doing this at home and using free tools. Is there a good free IDE?

Comment: @Raituha PyCharm Community Edition is free. Look here and scroll down to the version comparison. If the free features satisfy your needs, it's worth a look. :) https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Comment: Ok there is a Community Edition Pycharm for free :D